# spring batch - how to execute purge tasklet

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have written a simple spring batch tasklet which calls a dao method which in turn does some deletes. But I am not sure what I should be doing to call the job.

```
public class RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    private SpringBatchDao springBatchDao;

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
            throws Exception {
        contribution.incrementWriteCount(springBatchDao.purge());
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

So far to execute my spring batch jobs I am using quartz triggers with a setup like so. Each job has it's own xml file which has a read and a writer.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
           <list>
              <ref bean="dailyTranCountJobDetail" />
           </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
           <list>
              <ref bean="dailyTranCountCronTrigger" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dailyTranCountCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyTranCountJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="#{batchProps['cron.dailyTranCounts']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dailyTranCountJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.myer.reporting.batch.JobLauncherDetails" />
        <property name="group" value="quartz-batch" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="jobName" value="job-daily-tran-counts" />
                <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry" />
                <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And then here is an example of the job file itself with a reader and a writer.

```
<job id="job-daily-tran-counts" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="job-daily-tran-counts-step1">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="custDbTransactionManager">
            <chunk 
                reader="dailyTranCountJdbcCursorItemReader" 
                writer="dailyTranCountItemWriter" 
                commit-interval="1000" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="dailyTranCountJdbcCursorItemReader"
    class="com.myer.reporting.dao.itemreader.DailyTranCountJdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step"
    parent="abstractEposJdbcDao">
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.myer.reporting.dao.mapper.DailyTranCountMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dailyTranCountItemWriter" 
    class="com.myer.reporting.dao.itemwriter.DailyTranCountItemWriter" 
    parent="abstractCustDbJdbcDao"/>
```

Obviously for this new job there is no reader or writer. So what it he best/correct way for me to execute my new tasklet?

thanks

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#TaskletStep

Comment: Thanks. And I should clarify the bit that I'm confused about is how to define the tasklet. I'll check that doco

Answer (score 0):

I prefer java configuration instead of xml. You can configure your tasklet with the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchCleanUpJobsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Job batchCleanUpJob(final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                             final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                             final RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet removeSpringBatchHistoryTasklet) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("batchCleanUpJob")
        .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("batchCleanUpStep")
                   .tasklet(removeSpringBatchHistoryTasklet)
                   .build())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet batchCleanUpTasklet(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    final var tasklet = new RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet();
    tasklet.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    return tasklet;
  }
}
```

To schedule your new job use the following code:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchCleanUpJobsScheduler {

  private final Job batchCleanUpJob;
  private final JobLauncher launcher;

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * MON-FRI")
  public void launchBatchCleanupJob()
      throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
          JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    launcher.run(
        batchCleanUpJob,
        new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("launchTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters());
  }
}
```